# Magento 2 Category page showing 504 Gateway Timeout Error

Tags: magento2, nginx

My store is working fine which is developed in Magento 2 but when I am trying to access any category pages then I am getting 504 GATEWAY TIMEOUT.

I am using NGINX webserver.

This issue is only for category pages as other pages are working fine.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this @aallll?